# Why does SQL LIMIT clause returns random rows for every query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

It is a very simple query. For every query, I get a different result. Similar things happen when I used `TOP 1`. I would like a random sub-sample and it works. But am I missing something? Why does it return a different value every time?

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM table1 
where day_id>="2009-01-09" and day_id<"2011-02-16"
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: LIMIT without ORDER BY is a lottery. The same when the records are not unique using ordering expression - if LIMIT border divides the group with the same expression value then you have a lottery for this group.

Comment: @Akina, user_id is not unique in this table. I actually need a random sampled unique user_id. If LIMIT works randomly, it works perfect fine for my needs. SELECT DISTINCT not working with ORDER BY RAND() if only return user_id. Yes, maybe there are non records added in real time.

Comment: *If LIMIT works randomly, it works perfect fine for my needs.* In practice it is like-random. The record returned depends on the records order while scanning the table (physical order of records in memory during execution), for example, the order matches table's primary index in single-tabled fullscanned query. If you need the record to be really randomly selected you must use `ORDER BY RAND()`. In your particular case the record returned is defined by the physical record position during (after) the ordering for DISTINCT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL statements represent unordered sets, add `order by` clause such as

```
...
ORDER BY user_id
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Maybe... Personally, I try to get a deterministic sorting in most cases where `WITH TIES` is not available and applicable. Like `ORDER BY user_id, {primary key or another unique expression}`.

Comment: I need a random sub-sample of unique user_id. By adding ORDER BY RAND(), not working with SELECT DISTINCT.

Answer (score 3):

There's no guarantee that you will get a random result with your query. It's quite likely you'll get the same result each time (although the actual result returned will be indeterminate). To guarantee that you get a random, unique `user_id`, you should `SELECT` a random value from the list of `DISTINCT` values:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
      FROM table1 
      WHERE day_id >= "2009-01-09" AND day_id < "2011-02-16"
      ) u
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```